# Java compatible JVM language

Tags: java, jvm

Is there a JVM based language which is fully compatible with Java?

Why such a language can be useful:

1. There is an existing project with many lines of code written in Java and a team wants to switch to a new language with minimal effort. No translation needed.
2. A team is gradually starting to use new features of the new language. Some programmers write in old Java style. The others use the language fully.

Comment: You're looking for some mythical Java++, but you don't even know what Java++ does that makes it better than Java?  A project should only switch languages if the benefits of the new language outweigh the switching costs, so why even consider switching languages until you know the new language has benefits?

Comment: Yes, there is a JVM based language that is fully compatible with Java.  It's called Java.

Comment: Groovy is the most similar language to Java.

Answer (score 4):

You have many good options, I will list what I consider to be the leading 4 choices (in terms of technical maturity, size of community and general usefulness):

- **Clojure**: a JVM Lisp, emphasises dynamism and functional programming. A big paradigm shift, but very powerful/productive if you master it.
- **Scala**: Like Java++ with functional features and a powerful static type system. Probably the most advanced of the new JVM languages.
- **JRuby**: Ruby for the JVM. Great if your devs have Ruby experience or you need to port Ruby code to the JVM.
- **Groovy**: Very similar to Java, but as a dynamic scripting language. Probably the simplest to learn of the four languages listed here as it is syntactically very similar to Java.

All of these are "fully compatible" with Java in the sense that they can run on the same JVM and make full use of Java libraries / existing code bases.

It's perfectly feasible to migrate your team over time by writing new modules in the new language. Indeed, it is best to start small. Just make sure that you have developers who are eager to learn and supportive management.

Comment: I am asking about a Java compatible language rather than a JVM compatible language. Clojure compiler can not compile Java code (as well as Scala, JRuby and Groovy)

Comment: If you want Java then use Java I guess. But there's nothing to stop you having a single polyglot project that mixes Java and one or more of the languages above. I do that all the time (typically Java+Clojure in the same project in Eclipse). The Java compiler will compile the Java parts, and the Clojure compiler will compile the Clojure parts.

Comment: Finally I found the language which mostly satisfies my requirements. It is Xtend. The syntax is very close to Java.

Answer (score 1):

Groovy is probably your best bet. Most (but not quite all) Java code is valid Groovy code.